# RSA, p, q, n....if you know n, can't you always know p and q?

Tags: prime-factorization

So, I've only tested this for prime numbers 1-1000.  So I took two vectors, of prime numbers 1-1000 (one called p, one q) and took the permutations of each and multiply them to get "n"...you get 2*2, 2*3, 2*5 etc.

If I do this, I end up with all unique values for "n".

So in RSA security, wouldn't knowing n, allow a lookup list for the only combinations that create p and q?  Or am I just using too small of a sample 1-1000 and when you goto 256bit numbers there are no longer unique values of n?

Comment: I'll assume you're asking this question in good faith, but factoring large numbers is computationally very expensive, whereas finding large prime numbers is much easier. Encryption techniques like this (and any short of hashing for example) are theoretically reversible but difficult to reverse in practice.

Comment: "*when you goto 256 bit numbers there are no longer unique values of n?*"  What do you mean by this?  It sounds eerily like you are suggesting that numbers can be factored in multiple different ways... that different pairs of primes can multiply together to give the same result.  That is of course impossible... the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) directly implies that the factorizations of numbers into products of primes are unique (*up to order of factors and sign*)...

Comment: I suppose if you are constraining yourself to specific data types, yes computers will eventually have rounding errors... but RSA systems would use the correct data types to avoid these sorts of issues... properly using data types like BigInt which allow for exact correct calculation.

Comment: If $n=pq$ is a product of primes and $n<2^{256}$ then the smaller of $p$ and $q$ is less than $2^{128}$, but there are approximately $10^{74}$ prime numbers less than $2^{128}$, meaning that it would require about $10^{60}$ 1-terabyte hard drives to store the table of prime numbers you need to search through. Sometimes we forget just how BIG big numbers are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes, you can have a lookup table.

In practice, there isn't enough matter in the universe for you to store a lookup table large enough to help you find $p$ and $q$ from knowing $n=pq$ if $n$ is large enough.

For example, try finding $p,q$ if you know only that $$pq=225256289274304442252547699446950738681574839866362153899638597892648020191112400204675149178567891$$

Comment: Thank you!  I now get the elegance of the RSA solution....you simply can't have a "notebook" that hands out the keys...you just have to use the algorithm which isn't reasonably computational (with classic computing!) to force, but simple to verify.

Comment: Unless I missed something, that number is only 330 bits or so? In theory, it is crackable, though I agree it's still difficult

Comment: @BarryCarter The number is large enough for OP to understand the scope of the problem :)

Comment: For what its worth, the example above is quite small in comparison to what is currently in use, coming in at a mere 99 digits.  [RSA-250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-250) has been cracked in 2020 (*and might be current record holder?*) and has a whopping 250 decimal digits (829 bits).  Current keys in use are much larger than that and won't be crackable at this rate for quite some time.  For more interesting history, check ["the magic words are squeamish ossifrage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Words_are_Squeamish_Ossifrage)